# Generate a check constraint in PostgreSQL from JPA

Tags: jpa, constraints, postgresql-9.5, jpa-2.1

I am learning about JPA and PostgreSQL these days, I have a basic question: Is it possible to generate a `check` constraint in PostgreSQL from JPA?

I am using `JPA 2.1`.

Comment: What exactly do you want to check: Attribute values, e.g. length or uniqueness?

Comment: @MWiesner in fact I want to use check for complex checks, for instance I want to call functions in my check as we can do in PostgreSQL. You can imagine any possible use case of using `check`.